# How to compose thread safe operations and make them atomic?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Let's take a thread safe class like `LinkedBlockingDeque`:

```
BlockingQueue<Task> taskQueue = new LinkedBlockingDeque<Task>();
```

I know that operations like `take` and `put` are thread safe, so they respect the happened-before relationship.

But what if I want to compose some operations to make them atomic?
Like this:

```
if(taskQueue.size() == 1) {
   /*Do a lot of things here, but I do not want other threads
     to change the size of the queue here with take or put*/
}
//taskQueue.size() must still be equal to 1
```

If it was a not thread safe class, I could do something like this:

```
synchronized(taskQueue) {
  if(taskQueue.size() == 1) {
    /*Do a lot of things here, but I do not want other threads
      to change the size of the queue here with take or put*/
  }
  //taskQueue.size() must still be equal to 1
}
```

But it is not that simple, I do not think that the implementations of `take` and `put` use the object lock.

How do you handle this scanario?

Comment: It's easier to use a "normal" queue, and do the `synchronized`. There are more advanced techniques, they might be too complicated, and they may not actually be faster than simple locking.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I mean is composing some thread safe operations of a java thread safe class (like LinkedBlockingDeque) so difficult? My situation is very common by the way: I want to sometimes lock the whole queue for particular operations and sometimes exploit concurrent take and put.

Comment: Do you want the queue to remain unmodified, or do you instead want to do work on an unmodifiable snapshot of the queue while other threads can continue to mutate the original queue?

Comment: The first one. The real queue must stay unmodified.

Comment: FWIW, check out the `LinkedBlockingQueue#put(Object)`'s implementation: http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.java#LinkedBlockingQueue.put%28java.lang.Object%29 Looks like it is implemented with the higher level API from `java.util.concurrent`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do you handle this scenario?

In general, you cannot "compose" operations on the concurrent data structures without using external locking of some kind.  And when you do that, you reintroduce the concurrency bottleneck that you were trying to avoid by using the concurrent data structure.

In this case, you are correct.  The `LinkedBlockingDeque` class uses a private lock object for synchronization, etcetera.

Comment: *And when you do that, you reintroduce the concurrency bottleneck that you were trying to avoid by using the concurrent data structure*. Conceptually I think it was not clear to me the purpose of concurrent data structures. Thanks.